# Searching for Key, Value in a list of dictionaries

Tags: python

Answer to the question:

After some help, I realized that it was breaking because it was scanning through the emails and while one email would have what I was looking for, the rest didn't, and thus caused it to break.

Adding in a Try/Except solved the problem. Just for historical sake incase anyone else looks for a similar problem, this is the code that worked.

```
try:
  if (item for item in list_of_dict if item['name'] == "From" and item['value'] == 'NAME1 <name@some_email.com>').next():
    print('has it')
  else:
    pass
except StopIteration:
  print("Not found")
```

This way it would be able to scan through each email and have error handling if it broke, but if it found it be able to print that I found what I was looking for.

Original question:

Code:

`if (item for item in list_of_dict if item['name'] == "From" and item['value'] == 'NAME1 <name1@some_email.com>').next()`

I'm getting a `StopIteration` error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "quickstart1.py", line 232, in <module>
    main()
  File "quickstart1.py", line 194, in main
    if (item for item in list_of_dict if item['name'] == "From" and item['value'] == 'NAME1 <name1@some_email.com>').next():
StopIteration
```

This is my code:

```
if (item for item in list_of_dict if item['name'] == "From" and item['value'] == 'NAME1 <name1@some_email.com>').next():
      print('has it')
else:
  print('doesnt have it')
```

When I checked to see if I am putting in the iterator incorrectly, I did a lookup for item['value']:

`print((item for item in list_of_dict if item['name'] == "From").next())`

Returns:

```
{u'name': u'From', u'value': u'NAME1 <name1@some_email.com>'}
{u'name': u'From', u'value': u'NAME2 <name2@some_email.com>'}
```

Comment: `StopIteration` will be raised, when there's no matching values yield from generator. You have to use `try/except` approach.

Comment: Thank you! Didn't realize that's what stopIteration meant!

Comment: could you compress your question and include an [mcve] _without_ edits and clearly explain what's your input and expected output?

Comment: I don't get it. There is no search needed. That's the point of a dictionary. There is no point in having a list of dictionaries that have 2 values in them. Merge the dictionaries. Look up Tom, then check whether the answer is 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add another condition via `and`:

```
next(item for item in dicts if item["name"] == "Tom" and item["age"] == 10)
```

Note that [`next()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next) would throw a `StopIteration` exception if there is no match, you can either handle that via `try/except`:

```
try:
    value = next(item for item in dicts if item["name"] == "Tom" and item["age"] == 10)
    print(value)
except StopIteration:
    print("Not found")
```

Or, provide a *default value*:

```
next((item for item in dicts if item["name"] == "Tom" and item["age"] == 10), "Default value")
```

Comment: Hey @alecxe I updated my question. Getting an error. Can you see anything I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @MorganAllen okay, updated the answer for completeness sake.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if any dictionary contains it you could use the default argument of `next`:

```
iter = (item for item in list_of_dict if item['name'] == "From" and item['value'] == 'name <email>')

if next(iter, None) is not None: # using None as default
    print('has it')
else:
    print('doesnt have it')
```

but that would also exclude `None` regular items, so you could also use `try` and `except`:

```
try:
    item = next(iter)
except StopIteration:
    print('doesnt have it')    
else: 
    print('has it') # else is evaluated only if "try" didn't raise the exception.
```

---

But notice that a generator can only be used once, so recreate the generator if you want to use it again:

```
iter = ...
print(list(iter))
next(iter) # <-- fails because generator is exhausted in print

iter = ...
print(list(iter))
iter = ...
next(iter) # <-- works
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dicts = [
     { "name": "Tom", "age": 10 },
     { "name": "Pam", "age": 7 },
      { "name": "Dick", "age": 12 }
   ]

super_dict = {}    # will be {'Dick': 12, 'Pam': 7, 'Tom': 10}
for d in dicts:
    super_dict[d["name"]]=d['age']

if super_dict["Tom"]==10:
    print 'hey, Tom is really 10'
```